# Select 2 unique column in a query

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

How can I build a query with records such that 2 columns are unique?
This is my attempted code:

```
Select x.a, y.b
from table1 x, table2 y
where x.id = y.id;

1 - a
2 - b
3 - a
4 - b
5 - c
1 - c
6 - a
2 - a
should return this:
1 - a
2 - b
5 - c
```

But there is data loss, that's okay, I only want both unique columns.
I have tried to use **group by**, but that doesn't get the uniqueness of both.
To make it more descriptive about the intention behind:
table1 above stores classification, and table2 stores values. One classification can have multiple values and one value can belong to any number of classification. Now i want to pick all(or some) classifications from table1 and corresponding to each pick one value, condition is that the values should not repeat if it is picked with any other classification. Here in my example 1,2,3..6 are classifications and a,b,c are values. Now i want to pick classifications and corresponding values, i picked classification 1,2,5 and corresponding values a,b,c because all other classification will make the value repetition(say 3 will make value a repetition as a is already picked with classification 1).

Comment: What makes you choose 1-a over 2-a, 3-a, and 6-a?

Comment: In order to make the second values unique, you simple dismissed values from the first column. So if we are free to dismiss any values, would an empty result set suit you? It would contain no duplicates. If that would not suit you: By what rule do you allow or forbid removing values from the results?

Comment: Thorsten, if 1 - a is chosen then 2 - a can't be chosen as 'a' will be repetition. I have added the description.

Comment: i cant modify any data, the tables store mass data, i can just select.

Comment: But I could as well choose 6-a and dismiss 1-a then?

Comment: yes thorsten, if you choose 6-a then leave 1-a. I just need a classification and corresponding to that any single value that is not picked with other classification.

Comment: And I am not asking you to modify any data. I just want to know the rules you want to apply. As mentioned `select null, null from dual where 1=2` would already fulfill your requirements not to select any duplicates.

Comment: I am as confused as Thorsten. Is there more to the problem? Are you trying to select **as many rows as possible** (the largest possible number of rows) that satisfies your uniqueness requirement? If not, why do you need to select three rows, and not just the first two, or the last two?

Comment: mathguy, your question is very deep and interesting "am i trying to select as many rows as possible that satisfies this uniqueness!? Yes i want to select as many as possible OR i would say selected rows should be as many as classifications(less than or equal to 'Select distinct a from table1'). While if y.b already selected with any a(a - b) then i am not interested to select a` - b.

Comment: @mathguy this can be solved if i use java, i would select distinct a from table in a resultset. I will create a set S to store b. I'll iterate each of 'a' from resultset and for each 'a' i'll get distinct b. I'll iterate these b and check if b exist in set S, if not then i'll insert this b and pick next 'a' do the same. Finally i'll have a set S having b, each of which belong to different a. But achieving this using sql is bit challenging or tricky.

Comment: Don't expect to be able to solve this problem easily, and be suspicious of any solution you are developing on your own. What you are looking for is a **maximum bipartite matching**, a classical and difficult problem in graph theory. There are polynomial-time algorithms for solving it, and classes are already available in languages like Java. I don't know if anyone has coded any of them in PL/SQL, and it is quite unlikely that there will be a reasonably good solution in plain SQL.

Comment: oh man! you got it. It's a standard Problem. Thanks you.

Answer (score 3):

OP was looking for unique values (table2) with an arbitrary classification (table1).  As such, a method that can be used is to enumerate all the classification and value pairs within each group of values from table2 and then only select the first value from each group.

```
WITH
    enumerated_data AS
    (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY y.b ORDER BY x.a DESC) rn
            , x.a
            , y.b
        FROM        table1 x
        INNER JOIN  table2 y ON x.id = y.id
    )
SELECT  a, b
FROM    enumerated_data
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Consider adding some explanation to your answer.  Raw mystical code without context or explanation may not be very useful for people with similar but slightly different requirements.

Comment: added an explanation, please let me know if i should clarify more!

Comment: Isn't this simply `select max(a), b from ... group by b` only written more complicatedly?

Answer (score 1):

If your data is as you posted above, then it is already unique.

```
1 - a
2 - b
3 - a
4 - b
5 - c
1 - c
6 - a
2 - a
```

[1,a], [3,a], [6,a], [2,a] are all separate unique values.

You can use an aggregate function like min or max on the number portion if you want to match the data like that. Your desired output is not min or max though, so not really sure what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Jonofan, the data is unique collectively. But i want to refine it such that column 1 should be unique, also column 2. That's the only reason i require help from stackoverflow. Secondly, the data stored in these column is raw, cant take max/min of that.

Comment: @uniquephase, that makes more sense with your updated description. I can get pretty close to your desired output using a CTE with ROW_NUMBER query, but I'm pulling 1 - a where you want 5 - a. The query from user1327961 has the same issue. I think you might be able to do something with a recursive CTE, but can't quite get my head around it.

Comment: I think it is coincidental that @uniquephase mentioned "5 - c" should be returned as within the description it was mentioned arbitrary value was listed... I've added in an order by clause in my answer that will now return back "5 - c" but it it at the expense of changing the other output values as the _order by desc_ clause I included will not sort it by classification desc

Comment: Ah, okay. If that is the case then your query is fine. It sounded to me as though @uniquephase wanted both columns to be unique.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a two-level group by is required?

```
select     count(*), x.a, y.b
from       table1 x
inner join table2 y on x.id = y.id
group by   x.a, y.b;
```

Comment: i've tried that. It returns like 1 - a, 2 - b, 5 - c, 3 - a, 4 - b, 2 - a, 1 - c, 6 -a

Comment: Are you sure you tried grouping by both levels as seen in the code sample? Two-level group by will give unique set to both which is what you want based on description.  Or, are you saying you wanted column a to be unique completely and column b unique completely?

Comment: I want column a unique completely, and column b unique completely.